# How to get plain text from Wiki API subcategory

Tags: javascript, json, api, wikipedia

I am not able to get the plain text from a subcategory via the Wiki API.

I'm using

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Submarine&section=4&prop=extracts&explaintext&exsectionformat=plain&redirects
```

to fetch the abstract of a site from Wiki. Now I'd love to only get the content of let's say the 4th section. I tried by simply adding:

```
&section=4
```

No matter what I try, this just seems to be rejected. 
Though I'm able to get the content of a section using:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Submarine&prop=wikitext&explaintext&exsectionformat=plain&&format=json&origin=*&action=parse&section=4
```

But then I'm not able to get my text without the Wiki markdown.

Most likely the solution is a combination of those two approaches but I just can't wrap my head around it…

[These docs here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API) may help.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: There's no such thing. Your best bet is probably to fetch the HTML and turn it into text.

Comment: Hey @tgr, thanks a lot for your reply. Would you mind to explain a bit further how to do that?

Comment: Load it into some DOM library and take the `textContent` of the top node. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript/47140708#47140708) has an example for browser-based Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I‘ll dig into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution!**

After struggeling with the answer @Tgr gave me, i stumbled upon a mind-blowing JS lib:
**[wtf_wikipedia](https://beta.observablehq.com/@spencermountain/wtf_wikipedia)**.
I hope Wiki decides to give this man a medal! 
Fetching for example the text of the 8th category is as simple as this:

```
doc.sections(8).text()
```